# low resolution VGA monitors (640x480 or 480p) in Ubuntu

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I want to do some emulation on an external display. I have a Sony PGM2950Q monitor. This monitor is only capable of displaying 480p (640 x 480) at 31Hz. So it should be great for Mame.

Plugging it in to my Thinkpad T-61 (intel graphics) with Ubuntu 14.04.3 with VGA (via BNC breakout cable) results in a garbled / overlapping display running at the lowest setting of 800x600 @ 60Hz. I know the monitor works as have tested it previously.

What would be the best way to fix this? Ideally I want it to recognise a configured display rather than have to set it up every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xrandr`:

The commands to be executed in order:

```
cvt 640 480
xrandr --newmode "640x480_31.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

The part of the line after `xrandr --newmode` is similar to the ouput you should get when using the `cvt` command, so copy the output from the "resolution_refreshRate" ("640x480_31.00" here) point to the `+vsync` point and add it to `xrandr --newmode`.

Then:

```
xrandr --addmode LVDS1 resolution_refreshRate (don't use speechmarks)
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode resolution_refreshRate
```

If you want to make the changes permanent:

- Create a bash script, `xrandr.sh` for example, and place your xrandr commands into it:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  sudo xrandr --newmode ""640x480_31.00"" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
  sudo xrandr --addmode LVDS1 640x480_31.00
  xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 640x480_31.00
  ```
- Make the script executable with `chmod +x xrandr.sh`
- Search for "Startup Applications" in the dash, run it, and add the script as a startup application.

The commands will now run every time you log into your account.

**Note:** I'm using `LVDS1` as the supposed monitor name, but yours probably won't be the same. You can find your monitor name using:

```
xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }'
```